# Relating deformations of a scheme to deformations of its singular locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, deformation-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $X$ be a normal scheme with quotient singularities and $Y\subset X$ its singular locus. The first order deformations of $X$ are parametrized by $\mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\Omega_{X},\mathcal{O}_{X})$. This sheaf is supported on $Y$.

I would like to relate $\mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\Omega_{X},\mathcal{O}_{X})$ and $\mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\Omega_{Y},\mathcal{O}_{Y})$ (here I am considering first order deformations of $Y$ as an abstract scheme not its embedded deformations as a subscheme of $X$). To do this I am thinking to consider the conormal exact sequence 
$$\mathcal{I}_{Y}/\mathcal{I}_{Y}^{2}\rightarrow \Omega_{X|Y}\rightarrow\Omega_{Y}\mapsto 0$$
Applying $\mathcal{H}om(-,\mathcal{O}_{Y})$ we get
$$0\mapsto \mathcal{H}om(\Omega_{Y},\mathcal{O}_{Y})\rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(\Omega_{X|Y},\mathcal{O}_{Y})\rightarrow \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{I}_{Y}/\mathcal{I}_{Y}^{2},\mathcal{O}_{Y})\rightarrow \mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\Omega_{Y},\mathcal{O}_{Y})\rightarrow \mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\Omega_{X|Y},\mathcal{O}_{Y})\rightarrow \mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\mathcal{I}_{Y}/\mathcal{I}_{Y}^{2},\mathcal{O}_{Y})\rightarrow ....$$
*Is there any reason why one should have $\mathcal{E}xt^{1}(\mathcal{I}_{Y}/\mathcal{I}_{Y}^{2},\mathcal{O}_{Y}) = 0$ or $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{I}_{Y}/\mathcal{I}_{Y}^{2},\mathcal{O}_{Y}) = 0$ ?*

Comment: What scheme structure are you giving the singular locus?

Comment: Its reduced induced structure as a subscheme of $X$.

Comment: Ok, I would then say that you cannot expect that the $\mathcal{H}om(I_Y/I_Y^2, O_Y) = 0$.  In fact, I think it's basically never zero (think about the generic point of $Y$).  In terms of the $\mathcal{E}xt^1$, if $Y$ is Gorenstein, this might help as at least you could dualize the problem perhaps?  But $X$ just having quotient singularities probably won't help you.  Do you need general quotient singularities or do you have a particular variety in mind?  Are there any examples worth trying (say even in a computer?)

Comment: I need quotient singularities coming from the action of a finite group on a smooth scheme. Thank yuo very much.

Comment: Ok, what do you think the first interesting examples of such singularities might be for you?  (ie, which ones have you already done).

Comment: Does there exist the exact sequence $\mathcal{I}_{Y}/\mathcal{I}_{Y}^{2}\rightarrow\Omega_{X|Y}\rightarrow\Omega_{Y}\mapsto 0$ even if $X$ is singular and $Y$ is the singular locus of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.

Let $Y$ be a smooth variety over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $Y$, and let $X = Y/G$ be the quotient. Assume that the set of points where the isotropy is not trivial is in codimension greater or equal than three, that is the singular locus of $X$ is in codimension greater or equal than three. Then $Ext^1(\omega_X,\mathcal{O}_X) = 0$, that is $X$ is rigid.

One can find this in:

- M. Schlessinger, *"Rigidity of quotient singularities"*, Inventiones mathematicae, 1971, Volume 14, Issue 1, pp. 17-26.

This could fail is $X$ is singular in codimension two. For instance, we may consider the a singular point of type $\frac{1}{6}(2,4)$. Then, étale locally, in a neighborhood of $p$ the surface $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{2}/\mu_{6}$ where the action is given by 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mu_{6}\times\mathbb{A}^{2} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{A}^{2}\\
(\epsilon,x_{1},x_{2}) & \longmapsto & (\epsilon^{2}x_{1},\epsilon^{4}x_{2})
\end{array}
$$
The invariant polynomials with respect to this action are clearly $x_{1}^{3},x_{2}^{3},x_{1}x_{2}$. Therefore, étale locally, in a neighborhood of $p$ the surface $X$ is isomorphic to an étale neighborhood of singularity
$$S = \{f(x,y,z) = z^{3}-xy = 0\}\subset\mathbb{A}^{3}.$$
Now, we have 
$$Ext^{1}(\Omega_{S},\mathcal{O}_{S})\cong K[x,y,z]/(f,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}) = K[x,y,z]/(z^{3}-xy,-y,-x,3z^{2})\cong K[z]/(z^{2}).$$

Therefore $X$ is not rigid.